# FAST way to iterate over vertices and compute new attributes based on that of neighbors

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I'm doing a simple task: to iterate over all vertices and compute new attribute based on that of their neighbors. I search the SO and so far I know there are at least three way to do it:

1. Use ad_adj_list to create a adj list and then iterate over each element;
2. use sapply to iterate each vertex directly.

However, both methods take too long for the magnitude of my data (300k vertices and 8 million edges). Is there any fast way to loop over vertices? thanks!

For benchmark, say I have the following sample data:

```
set.seed <- 42
g <- sample_gnp(10000, 0.1)
V(g)$name <- seq_len(gorder(g)) # add a name attribute for data.table merge
V(g)$attr <- rnorm(gorder(g))
V(g)$mean <- 0 # "mean" is the attribute I want to compute
```

The code for method 1. is that:

```
al <- as_adj_list(g)
attr <- V(g)$attr
V(g)$mean <- sapply(al, function(x) mean(attr[x])) 
# took 28s
# most of the time is spent on creating the adj list
```

The code for method 2. is that:

```
compute_mean <- function(v){
    mean(neighbors(g, v)$attr)
}
V(g)$mean <- sapply(V(g), compute_mean)  # took 33s
```

I BELIEVE that igraph-R SHOULD NOT be so slow in interating vertices, otherwise, this will make analysis of large graph with size of millions impossible, which task I think should be quite common to R users!

### Update

According to @MichaelChirico's comment, now I came up with a third method: import the graph structure into a data.table and do the calculation with the data.table `by` syntax, as follows:

```
gdt.v <- as_data_frame(g, what = "vertices") %>% setDT() # output the vertices
gdt.e <- as_data_frame(g, what = "edges") %>% setDT() # output the edges
gdt <- gdt.e[gdt.v, on = c(to = "name"), nomatch = 0] # merge vertices and edges data.table
mean <- gdt[, .(mean = mean(attr)), keyby = from][, mean]
V(g)$mean <- mean 
# took only 0.74s !!
```

The data.table way is **MUCH** faster. However, its result is **NOT** exactly identical to that of the first two methods. Besides, I'm very disappointed to see that I have to rely on another package to do such a simple task, which I thought should be the strength of igraph-R. Hope I'm wrong!

Comment: Perhaps look into using `data.table` / `findinterval`

Comment: @MichaelChirico, ah, I think I got your idea, do you mean first import the graph structure into a data.table, and then do calculation using the data.table's fast grouping feature?  I tried and it was MUCH faster than the igraph way. However, that's not elegant for me: fast iterating over vertices should be a basic feature for any graph package. It is a pity that a particular SNA package user has to turn to other package to do some basic SNA calculation!

Comment: can't say I disagree. the beauty of R is you could write your own package! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where is the actual problem... When I re-run your code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
set.seed <- 42
g <- sample_gnp(10000, 0.1)
V(g)$name <- seq_len(gorder(g)) # add a name attribute for data.table merge
V(g)$attr <- rnorm(gorder(g))
V(g)$mean <- 0 # "mean" is the attribute I want to compute
gg <- g
```

... and compare the two methods in expressions `e1` and `e2`

```
e1 <- expression({
  al <- as_adj_list(gg)
  attr <- V(gg)$attr
  V(gg)$mean <- sapply(al, function(x) mean(attr[x]))  
})

e2 <- expression({
  gdt.v <- as_data_frame(g, what = "vertices") %>% setDT() # output the vertices
  gdt.e <- as_data_frame(g, what = "edges") %>% setDT() # output the edges
  gdt <- gdt.e[gdt.v, on = c(to = "name"), nomatch = 0] # merge vertices and edges data.table
  mean <- gdt[, .(mean = mean(attr)), keyby = from][, mean]
  V(g)$mean <- mean 
})
```

The timings are:

```
microbenchmark(e1, e2)

## Unit: nanoseconds
##  expr min lq  mean median uq max neval cld
##    e1  47 47 51.42     48 48 338   100   a
##    e2  47 47 59.98     48 48 956   100   a
```

So very similar, and the results

```
all.equal(V(g)$mean, V(gg)$mean)

## [1] TRUE
```

... are the same.